# How to store slider value when finger is lifted from a jQuery Mobile Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I want to store the value of the slider in the alert message in the code below where I have the place holder `alert('stop')`

```
 <head>
    <title>Page 1</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/ui.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.min.css" />



    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function () {
         //depending on the device we have a touch or a mouse event
         var supportTouch = jQuery.support.touch,
         touchStartEvent = supportTouch ? "touchstart" : "mousedown",
         touchStopEvent = supportTouch ? "touchend" : "mouseup",
         touchMoveEvent = supportTouch ? "touchmove" : "mousemove";

         //the event is binded to the .ui-slider inside of the input type range
     jQuery('#msBig').siblings('.ui-slider').bind(touchStopEvent,function() {
             alert('stop')
         });
    });
  </script>


 </head>
 <body>
     <div id="page1" data-role="page">
         <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Page Title</h1>
          </div><!-- /header -->
          <div data-role="content">

              <input type="range" id="msBig" value="50"    tabindex="0"   data-theme="b" max="100"  min="0" size="3"  />

          </div><!-- /content -->
          <div data-role="footer">
              <h4>Page Footer</h4>
          </div><!-- /footer -->
     </div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

I found the code at the following site:
https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-execute-javascript-code-when-finger-is-lifted-from-a-slider

I have tried various solutions but come up empty handed. 
`var selection = $(".selector").slider("value");` is in the jQuery API but I do not know how to implement it in the code above.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/FaWbZ/ listen to `change` event. you dont need to handle it yourself with touch events.

Comment: I need the value when the user lifts their finger from the slider. In change event the value continually updates. The first answer works but when I try to call the page with the slider from another page it no longer works. Any ideas?

Comment: `$("#page_id #msBig").val()` if you want to call it from another page.

Comment: Can you elaborate where I would put "$("#page_id #msBig").val()" in the function call"jQuery('#msBig').val();" or where ?

Comment: Please update your question with more details, i.e. when do you want to get the value of the slider and from which page.

Comment: I need to get the value of the slider when the user lifts their finger up from the slider control. The value could be returned from the slider page.

Comment: it's a bit tricky since you need to go inside dynamic classes created by jQM http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/FaWbZ/ but it works

Comment: I tried the jsFiddle but the alert was never triggred.

Comment: try now same fiddle, i added `mouseup` if you're using mouse not touch.

Comment: Works! Do I just leave mousup out when deploying to a phone?

Comment: there's no harm in leaving it. it wont trigger anyway on touch devices.

Comment: I just installed the code on a Android device and no alert is ever triggered. I tried it with mouseup included and left out both do not work. Is there any other way to do this so it always works?

Comment: Have you used `pageinit` instead of `.ready()`?

Comment: Yes, $(document).on("pageinit", function () { ...